# IPv4 forward on windows?

Tags: windows, tcpip, forwarding, ipv4, redirection

Is there anything that can forward/redirect all incoming traffic to another ip. Basically I'm looking the windows equivalent of ip forwarding in linux.

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_foward
```

Answer (score 3):

The direct equivalent is a registry setting.  It varies on different versions of Windows but on XP it's:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\IPEnableRouter`

See this [list](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/w2kprout.html)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an article on [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/redirsrvr.aspx) about redirecting traffic to another address, you specify the source ip address and port, the destination ip address and port and the traffic gets redirected...written in C# .NET.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps [Internet Connection Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Connection_Sharing)?